# Show modal when the condition is not met

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

This is what I want to do: The user has to complete a form and if the quantity of items is odd a modal should pop up with a message, if the quantity is even then the form should be submitted and no modal should pop up. I am trying to do it in JavaScript using AJAX but with no success. I am new into JavaScript. Any help and ideas are welcome.
This is the code I have so far.

```
  //this is the submit button, 
  //which if is pressed and the number is odd should trigger the modal
  <input id="myButton" type="submit" class="button_submit" value="Submit">

  <input type="submit" id='myButton' class="button_continue" value="Submit anyway !">
  <a id='button_back' class="button_back">Take me back !</a>
  //these 2 buttons are on the modal, they work

<script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        var button = document.getElementById('myButton')
        var page = document.getElementById('content')
        var back = document.getElementById('button_back')
        var message = document.getElementById('warning_msg')
        var item = parseInt(qty_item) (this is the input)


        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (item % 2 != 0) {
            button.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = 'flex';
               message.innerHTML='You cannot have an odd number.';
               console.log('Log in 1');
            }
        }
      } else {
        button.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = 'none';
           console.log('Log in 2');
      }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "/new");
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    console.log('About to send')
    xhr.send();
    console.log("This has worked")
```

Comment: You have 2 buttons with the same `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the odd/even condition into the button click event as below:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  button.onclick = function() {
    if (item % 2 !== 0) {
      modal.style.display = 'flex';
      message.innerHTML = 'You cannot have an odd number.';
      console.log('Log in 1');
    } 
    else {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
      console.log('Log in 2');
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover, change the `id` attribute of the 2nd button, because `id` has to be unique

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me solve the task!